# Google Sheets - Dependant Data Validation Rules

Tags: google-sheets

I currently use formulas to get a dependant data validation lists based on cell values.

This is the range i use for data validation from range:

```
='List - Item'!F2:Y2
```

applied to range

```
Master!D2:D1350
```

This is the equation I use to determine the dependant values

```
=iferror(transpose(index($A$2:$B$11,,match(Master!B2,$A$1:$B$1,0))),"")
```

The problem I have is every time I sort the range

```
Master!D2:D1350
```

Or try to insert a new row, the data validation is split into multiple data validation rules and everything is screwed up!

How to bypass this??

My data validation rules to create dependant drop list is always ruined when I sort the table I have or insert a new row.

Comment: Can you create a table or a range, and use this range or this table in your function ? Instead of A1:H45 fo exemple.

It should update automatically when adding a row

Comment: My current problem is when I sort the table "where I use the data validation" or if I insert a new row

The rules I have for data validation update and break down into multiple ranges and that does not work as the rules don't work anymore

Comment: Ok, And I suggest that you use a Named Range.

It should not break the range, just add a row to that range, and then keep you data validation

Comment: Yes but you can't use named ranges in data validation apply to range